# Azure Data Lake file properties and/or checksum

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to write a process that will skip execution of some processing jobs based upon whether data in the file has changed, and I would like to do this via checksum. Is there any way (currently or on the roadmap) to give visibility into a file's MD5 checksum or similar?

Alternatively, can I tag a file with a "property" such as a checksum of the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1, unfortunately there is no such capability available.

Such capabilities will be available through ADLS Gen2, since it is built on Blob Storage - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/data-lake-storage/ .

Thanks,
Sachin Sheth
Program Manager, ADLS.